# Full stack framework for Java

Tags: java, entity-framework, frameworks, domain-driven-design

I'm looking for a full stack framework (from persistency to view generation (CRUD)) for Java. I don't have experience with Rails style frameworks, like Grails, but I worked a lot with Hibernate, Struts, Spring ...

I prefer a framework that let you naturally modify the business domain design with the less effort ( i.e. writing the sql querys to modify the tables and constrains, change the view pages, etc ... ). I was looking a bit about this topic, I saw Naked Objects for example but its development has stopped.
 So, I want to hear about your experience.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Better late than never :) 
there is a new Full Stack Java Framework avaible now called CUBA platform . Please find more infor at  https://www.cuba-platform.com/

Comment: Short update about the CUBA Platform. The platform is going opensource soon and will be distributed under the Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 5):

Grails is the closest thing I know of to a full stack framework in Java (at least for general web apps).  You define the domain objects and use them in your Grails controllers and views.  To generate the tables, you use the GORM utility to create them from your domain objects.

Comment: Grails is the closest, but it's mainly known as a Groovy framework though.

Comment: I disagree - Groovy might be the glue, but it's all Spring and Hibernate underneath.  The generated code is Java AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah on this inside it is Java, but from what I have seen, end users build on it with Groovy and GSP pages more often than with straight Java and JSP.

Comment: Grails can be thought of as a DSL for Spring and Hibernate. However, the question asks for Java... Groovy can be used in a way very similar to Java but Grails would be awkward. The bigger question is if there is anyway the original poster can break from the shackles of Java.

Comment: Hi Michael, while Groovy lets me work with full compatibility between Java <=> Groovy I think that Groovy will be ok for me. I don't know if I will feel good with a dynamic typing language, does the refactor works good with groovy?
 Thanks!

Comment: @jonathan: last time I looked at grails (I even have 3 apps working with it, one of them I use daily), the tools where not as mature and well-working as those I'm used in java.

Refactoring, code completion and such things that rely on the possibility of identifying the type of a variable at compiletime, will always be easier to develop and therefore work better for static and typesafe languages.

So I myself am going back to plain Java. That said, the choice is not easy - options include Seam, Rife, Play, AppFuse. I'm beginning to write a medium-complex app with each of them.

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, development hasn't stopped on Naked Objects, and we quietly released Naked Objects 4.0 a few months ago.  There are also a number of sister projects that I have worked on, extending the capabilities of the framework.  In addition, my book, "Domain Driven Design using Naked Objects", was released just before Xmas.

For more details, see:

1. [naked objects](http://nakedobjects.org)
2. [star objects: sister projects to naked Objects](http://starobjects.sourceforge.net)
3. [my book's website](http://pragprog.com/titles/dhnako)
4. [my blog](http://danhaywood.com)

Cheers
Dan

Comment: I am going to check look at the links. Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 3):

Two other full stack frameworks are Play (www.playframework.org) and Web4J (www.web4j.com).  I never used either one, but both seem interesting.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to go a very long way with just JSPs written with JSTL and JDBC.

If you've mastered that, I'd say that Spring alone would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I use all what you said. But for every change that I do to the business domain I have to do a lot of well know steps to the code (and to the database) to get the CRUD of the domain changes.
I could make a plugin Eclipse to make this easier but it will be a tool especific for my domain, or my way to develop applications. I was looking at Spring Roo, I'm still looking.  Thanks Duffy.

Comment: Spring Roo just had release 1.0.  Personally, I'd prefer Grails before Roo.  I think it has more traction right now.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) which is a Spring project based on what you already know, ie Spring, Hibernate, but that gets you up to speed fast, by adopting a Convention over Configuration philosophy.

There is a blog post that [describes the steps for creating a blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2/) that might explain better what I mean

Answer (score 2):

Take 5 minutes for look at Ninja Framework : [website](http://www.ninjaframework.org/)

You will love it.

This is using java the closest implementation to a script language like Python or PHP.

It has ultrafast development flow that resembles PHP flow: they call it *SuperDevMode*.

Answer (score 1):

Openxava, this is the right tool for your needs.
It's a Domain Driven Framework, you just write your JPA model class and Openxava generates de interface, with easily customizable view, actions and controllers.

visit: www.openxava.org

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JRapid](http://www.jrapid.com). Using JRapid you define your application using Domain Driven Design and it generates all the layers for your web app, from database to a powerful UI.

Comment: It´s good to see a framework development in Argentina. Keep on!